# How to make large size(large resolution) images fit to every screen size,How to avoid it going beyond the screen

Tags: html, css, ipad

I'm making a few HTML pages specifically for iPad Air and iPad Mini. The pages will have few larges images, for example of the size of 1600x300. But as per the code which was written by me the images are too big to be on the screen, it goes beyond the screen while testing in Windows browsers. Code as shown below:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
.image1 {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px
}
.image2 {
    width: 1700px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 450px;
    left: 100px
}
```

The width and height of div are set the same as width and height of the image. The images size were specifically designed for iPad, I can't change the size.

If I give the actual resolution of iPad for `.wrapper` as shown below the images will get positioned correctly when I test I the browser setting the screen size to 1024x768 (logical resolution of iPad).

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 2048px;
    height: 1536px
}
```

I want the image to adapt to all screen as well as iPad by giving 100% width and height to wrapper class so that even in the portrait mode of iPad I can view it without any fluctuations. Please tell me how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using DIVs instead of `<img>` tags?

Comment: No,there will be no contents laid over any image.I have 2 images one below each other and a text after them of around 8 word with a font size of 60.I was told to put any content with in a div tag.Is there any particular reason for it??

Comment: Based on your response I would go with `<img>` tags then, see my answer below. It might be a bit of semantics but to me placing images in a `<div>` (`<div><img></div>`) is not the same as setting an image as the background of a `<div>`. A lot of times your content will be placed inside a `<div>`, but it they can be placed inside almost any tag.

Comment: Thank flr the response.I have few more question,what if want to place large images,say sizes of 400x400 of around 10 images one beside each other and make them to adapt to every screen size? What should be the warpper width and height?? Because I want the background to be black.It would be good if u can show the html and css part.

Comment: I'm not sure what the layout you're suggesting would look like.

Answer (score 1):

OP hasn't clarified why they're using DIVs. Maybe there's going to be content laid over it? Until OP provides clarification I'm going to provide the standard responsive image solution.

If you don't have to use DIVs, try this:

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/1600x300">
<img src="http://placehold.it/1600x300">
```

```css
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwzn2db6/

**UPDATE**

***Note:*** I cannot tell if you're also looking for a 100% height option or just need the widths to be a 100% width and scale.

If you'd like to use DIVs you could use [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) along with the appropriate amount of `padding-bottom` for each image DIV. The padding on the bottom of the DIV is based on the image's height to width ratio expressed as a percentage.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-1"></div>
    <div class="img-2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container > div {
    background-size: contain;
}
.img-1 {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1600x300/') no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 18.75%; /* 300/1600 * 100 = 18.75 */ 
}
.img-2 {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1600x300') no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 25%; /* 400/1600 * 100 = 25 */
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kjtdhmn/

Either of the solutions offered above may not be a 100% what you're looking for as it is hard to tell what the proper context and final objective is.

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-width: 100%` and `height:auto` to your images

Comment: I just want 3 images of big size placed  below each other and a big text after it adapt to the screen size

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to adjust size (width-height) of pages according to the device, so you might need the following tag added to your  section of your HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
......
......
```

content="width=device-width" will adjust screen resolution automatically'initial-scale' value used to set zoom level of page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what's with people saying stuff isn't an answer? Expecially when it is? Wtf.

Second of all, another acceptable answer on top of what was already said by DigitalDouble, would be to set the image to have the
Background-size:cover;  and set the image with css background-image property.

I would remove the pixel sizes entierly and just set it to 100% width and height, with position Absolute to be able to lay other content on top of it.

Comment: This seems like a partial answer. Setting 100% width and 100% height doesn't seem to help. Not really sure where the absolute positioning fits in either. If you're setting the image as the background, why not place the content inside that element? Could you please provide a working example as I have tried you're suggestions and haven't had any success (http://jsfiddle.net/rwzn2db6/). I do totally agree with you about DigitalDouble's answer as being valid.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rwzn2db6/9/)

 You won't see this working 100% in JS Fiddle because it's inside an iframe...

Another solution - if you need the images to maintain aspect ratio across browsers is to use percentages for their heights...

assuming 300+400=700 - ipad screen width - 
100/700 = 0.1428571428571429 <- ratio

300 tall is - 300*ratio = 42.85%
400 tall is - 400*ratio = 57.14%
Let's round out

300  = 43%
400 = 57%

and that would get the split to sort of maintain an aspect ratio when stretching a background even up to cover a 4k monitor.

Comment: iframe on jsFiddle aren't the issue. The implementation is faulty, https://jsfiddle.net/rwzn2db6/14/. The image widths need to be responsive also. You don't need to set `width: 100%;` for block level elements, they already take up 100% width.